# Max parms for delegates Action/Func is 8 in NET source code, 16 in metadata, why?

Tags: c#

I can declare a delegate variable with up to 16 parameters for both built-in delegates Action() and Func()
When I run Go To Definition on Action() and Func(), I also get the max 16, but this is taken [from metadata]. For example, these two lines compile fine:

```
Action<float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float> MAction;
Func  <float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float> MFunc;
```

However, the actual source code for NET 4.6 shows max count 8 for parameters of Action() and Func(), in the source code file action.cs - Why the discrepancy?

This is [from metadata]

```
 #region Assembly System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
 // C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Core.dll
 #endregion
 namespace System
 {
      public delegate TResult Func<in T1, in T2, in T3, in T4, in T5, in T6, in T7, in T8, in T9, in T10, in T11, in T12, in T13, in T14, in T15, in T16, out TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7, T8 arg8, T9 arg9, T10 arg10, T11 arg11, T12 arg12, T13 arg13, T14 arg14, T15 arg15, T16 arg16);
 }
```

The file action.cs shows max 8

```
 public delegate TResult Func<in T1, in T2, in T3, in T4, in T5, in T6, in T7, in T8, out TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7, T8 arg8);
```

Comment: Please provide the link you are using to check the source. also the commented out section from the metadata page's header would be useful to check which assembly you are looking in. Please add both to your question as a edit

Comment: I am not concerned about the count but the discrepancy between two sources that are supposed to be the same thing

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy is because you are looking at the source for the wrong file. For 0-8 types they exist in `mscorlib.dll`, however for more than 8 types those are defined in `System.Core.dll`.

You can see the difference if you look at the `Assembly:` in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402868(v=vs.110).aspx) for [them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[Action.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Utils/Action.cs). They're in a separate source file in a separate project for a separate assembly, that's why they're a bit hard to find, but they're there.